# Hiding table rows content on checkbox tick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm currently stuck on hiding and showing content on my webpage. The content is showing servers being online or offline. As this list is long I want to hide all servers showing as "LIVE" but the deployments that are "DOWN" will still be visible.

Ticking the box would hide all the content in the `<td>` tags that are equal to "LIVE" but the `<td>` tags that are equal to "DOWN" will still be visible.

```html
<span class="text-default">
  <input type="checkbox" style="display: none" class="down-checkbox" id="down" checked>
  <label for="down-checkbox">Only show offline servers</label>
</span>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>No.</th>
    <th>Server</th>
    <th>URL</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      $tests = array(array("test","test.test.test"));
      $i = 1;
      foreach($tests as $test => $testProperties)
      {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$i</td>";
        echo "<td>".$testProperties[0]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$testProperties[1]."</td>";
        if ($socket =@ fsockopen($testProperties[1], 80, $errno, $errstr, 1)) 
        {
          echo "<td><span class='badge badge-success'>LIVE</span></td>";
          fclose($socket);
        }
        else 
        {
          echo "<td><span class='badge badge-danger'>DOWN</span></td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$("down-checkbox").click(function() {
  $("<td><span class='badge badge-success'>LIVE</span></td>").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it i recon, Code amended was:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#hidelive').click(function(e) {
$.each($(".badge"), function(){
if($(this).is(':contains("LIVE")')) {
$(this).closest("tr").toggle();
}
});
});
});
</script>

<div id="hidelive">Only show offline servers</div>
```

The servers now hide on the text click :)

Thanks everyone for the suggestions! Much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

There's several issues with your logic:

- `$("down-checkbox")` is not a valid selector. You're missing the leading `.` for the class selector.
- The checkbox is not visible. Remove `display: none`
- The `for` attribute of the `label` should reference the `id` of the `input`, not its `class`.
- Use the `change` event when dealing with checkboxes, not `click`, as the latter has issues with accessibility.
- You're placing a HTML string in the jQuery selector to look for the 'LIVE' text. That's incorrect as it will *create* the element. To *search* for an element use a valid selector. In this case you could search for `.badge-success` to retrieve the live instances only, then `closest()` to get its parent `tr`.
- `hide()` will never make the row reappear when the checkbox is checked again. A better idea is to use `toggle()` passing the boolean `checked` state of the checkbox in order to hide/show as required.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.down-checkbox').change(function() {
    $('.badge-danger').closest('tr').toggle(this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="text-default">
  <input type="checkbox" class="down-checkbox" id="down" checked>
  <label for="down">Only show offline servers</label>
</span>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Server</th>
      <th>URL</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test.test.test</td>
      <td><span class="badge badge-success">LIVE</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test.test.test</td>
      <td><span class="badge badge-danger">DOWN</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test.test.test</td>
      <td><span class="badge badge-success">LIVE</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test.test.test</td>
      <td><span class="badge badge-danger">DOWN</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The checkbox is not visible but the text itself is, I do not want to add the 
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test.test.test</td>
      <td><span class="badge badge-danger">DOWN</span></td>
    </tr>
to the code since there are over 200 servers, this is why I handled it with the php script.

Comment: 1) In which case you could leave the checbox hidden and just rely on people clicking the `label`, however this is non-standard behaviour. Users are not expecting to click unstyled text and have it perform an action. By showing the checkbox it's purpose as a toggle (as well as its current state) becomes clear. 2) You can use your current PHP. I simply extracted the HTML in to this example for the purpose of demonstration as the PHP is irrelevant

Comment: Also note that for the `label` to toggle the checkbox the `for` attribute should match the `id` of the input, not its `class`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $("down-checkbox").click(function(){
        $("td .badge").each(function(){
            if($($this).text() == "LIVE"){
                $($this).hide();
            }
            else if($($this).text() == "DOWN"){
                $($this).show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

you can also use the reverse logic to show and hide based LIVE/DOWN status

Comment: Thank you Alpesh, this, however only hides the badge and not the whole <tr> tag for a server that is "LIVE" :)

Comment: Replace $($this).hide(); with $($this).parents('tr').hide(); to hide the entire row and same for $($this).show(); with $($this).parents('tr').show();

Answer (score 0):

Would totally go with Rory's nice answer, but if you don't care about refactoring at the moment, give jQuery [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector a try:

```
$('span.badge.badge-success:contains("LIVE")').hide();
```

Note that you do NOT put the HTML tag inside of it, because by doing that you are actually [creating a new element](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#creating-new-elements) instead of manipulating the existing ones.

---

Just for the sake of showing my point, here's a quick demo highlighting the difference between the two approaches:

```js
$('#btn-create').click(function() {
  // This will create a new element dynamically 
  // and append it onto a div with class "container"
  $('<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />').appendTo('div.container');
});

$('#btn-manipulate').click(function() {
  // This will manipulate the existing "img" element instead of creating a new, similar element
  $('img').css('width', '150px');
})
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Initially empty -->
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="btn-create">Create new element</button>
  <button id="btn-manipulate">Manipulate existing element</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The script, what you need is like this:

```
<script>
$(".down-checkbox").click(function(){
    $.each($(".badge.badge-success"), function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

The jQuery select all ".badge.badge-success" classed rows, which are the Live servers, and the remaining list will contain only the DOWN servers.